# Unauthorized Error when call the service using the token returned by ADAL: Active Directory .Net Native Desktop?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to learn more about Azure Active Directory. I'm looking at the Code Samples at:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/

The first sample I ran on my local is: NativeClient-DotNet, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop .

I follow the steps, the ADAL returns the token successfully, see below screen shot.
[image]

However, when I use the token to call the to do list service, it always fails. The error is:

[image]
Status Code: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized... (see the 1st screen shot).

Anyone knows what issue this is? Since it is sample code, I guess maybe just something I miss.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the steps correctly ? Where is it failing at ? Does it even reach the controller in todo service ?

Comment: Yes, I followed all steps, at least I think so. From 1st screenshot, you can see it actually gets the token from AD, but it failed when try to call the service, shown in the second screen shot. Thanks

Comment: Take the AccessToken and put it in http://jwt.calebb.net/ and paste the output into your question so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: @urlreader did you resolve your issue and what was the problem. I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following the direction given by @Saca's comment in the question... I pasted my token at [jwt.celebb.net](http://jwt.calebb.net/).

I found that the *aud* (audience) property had a mismatching value... :|
I spent more than 2 hours to figure this out while fiddling with Azure Portal applications' settings and the code...

[image]

In my **Web API** I had this in `Web.config`:

```
<add key="ida:Audience" value="api://49111627-c20d-45b0-9823-d3bbd8689916" />
```

While in the **Client** `Web.config` I had this:

```
<add key="todo:TodoListResourceid" value="49111627-c20d-45b0-9823-d3bbd8689916" />
```

You see the mismatch... they're different. There's an extra `api://` there and so I was getting the Unauthorized exception.